# TextField inside CupertinoAlertDialog

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-cupertino, flutter-textinputfield

I'm making a dialog, which has a text field to get input from user, by using `CupertinoAlertDialog`. However, it keeps saying **No Mater Widget Found**. I searched and tried with some solution from the Internet but it didn't work.
Here is my code

```
showCupertinoDialog(
   context: context,
   builder: (context) {
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
     content: Scaffold(
     body: TextField(
     controller: cubit.textEditingController,
     ),
    ),
   );
 }
);
```

I have tried to replace `Material` with `Card`, `Scaffold` and `Container` but it didn't work as well.

Please help me

Comment: please add your code, not image

Comment: Yes, I added it

Comment: You are trying this in iOS or Android ?

Comment: I'm trying this in Android

Comment: Sorry Jahidul Islam, I don't get your point about passing context where I call the function. Isn't it context : context in my code?

Comment: Could you provide the full class code please to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Wrap your cupertinoAlertDialog inside ShowDialog as it has Material Widget property.

```
showDialog<bool>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Cupertino dialog'),
                  content: Card(
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Name",
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
```

Comment: please mark the solution as correct if it works for you @Hoangdz